# What is the difference between "create_users" and "add_users" capabilities?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, user-access

The codex lists both **create_users** and **add_users** under [roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

Does anyone know what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I explored WordPress to find difference between it and in schema.php file i found the following function only where in WordPress add_users capability is used.

```
/**
 * Create and modify WordPress roles for WordPress 3.0.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
function populate_roles_300() {
$role =& get_role( 'administrator' );

if ( !empty( $role ) ) {
    $role->add_cap( 'update_core' );
    $role->add_cap( 'list_users' );
    $role->add_cap( 'remove_users' );

    // Never used, will be removed. create_users or
    // promote_users is the capability you're looking for.
    $role->add_cap( 'add_users' );

    $role->add_cap( 'promote_users' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_themes' );
    $role->add_cap( 'export' );
}
}
```

Based on the comment written in code i think that the add_users capability is only used for backward compatibility and can be removed in future version of WordPress so we should use create_users capability instead of add_users capability.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure, but afaik WordPress added those when the meta capabilities for Post types got added. There're a bunch of capabilities for posts, pages and CPTs that can be either mapped to the default `*_post` caps or set to custom ones like `create_issues` for an `issues` CPT. And as `create_posts` came with one of the more current versions, I'm pretty sure that the same goes for `create_users`.

- You can't create a user unless you have `promote_users`.

Let's say we'd like to give an editor some extra capabilities concerning users:

- `list_users` does just what it says.
- `edit_users` allows him to edit user accounts with an inferior role (author/contributor/subscriber).
- `create_users` does not work at all without `promote_users` (returns "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.").

I'm not sure when [the patches](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16501) will move in (they've "commit" state for two years now).